# POST requests to php only appearing in $_GET var

Tags: php, post

I am sending POST data to a php page and receiving it by `var_dump($_POST)`. However the `$_POST` is always empty and the `$_GET` contains the values. I'm certain its a POST request and have tested in Postman REST client and cURL. I am using PHP 5.5.3 and Apache 2.2.
Thanks

EDIT:
I'm using the php scripts as an api so currently I am testing using the above mentioned tools to test the request using POST.
For example I am using this cURL request `curl -X POST http://dev/project/build/api/registrants.php?hello=there`

Contents of my $_SERVER (redacted in areas)

```
array(25) {
  ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=>
  string(11) "curl/7.37.1"
  ["HTTP_HOST"]=>
  string(3) "dev"
  ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=>
  string(3) "*/*"
  ["PATH"]=>
  string(29) "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
  ["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=>
  string(67) "Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 PHP/5.5.3"
  ["SERVER_NAME"]=>
  string(3) "dev"
  ["SERVER_ADDR"]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  ["SERVER_PORT"]=>
  string(2) "80"
  ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=>
  string(25) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"
  ["SERVER_ADMIN"]=>
  string(15) "you@example.com"
  ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=>
  string(59) "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/build/api/registrants.php"
  ["REMOTE_PORT"]=>
  string(5) "51096"
  ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=>
  string(7) "CGI/1.1"
  ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=>
  string(8) "HTTP/1.1"
  ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["QUERY_STRING"]=>
  string(10) "hello=there"
  ["REQUEST_URI"]=>
  string(45) "/project/build/api/registrants.php?hello=there"
  ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=>
  string(34) "/project/build/api/registrants.php"
  ["PHP_SELF"]=>
  string(34) "/project/build/api/registrants.php"
  ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=>
  float(1416256385.03)
  ["REQUEST_TIME"]=>
  int(1416256385)
  ["argv"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "hello=there"
  }
  ["argc"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

Comment: Going to need to see some code if this is a question

Comment: What is the question? We're going to see how you're sending in order to help you work this out.

Comment: Might there be some stupid proxy between client and server?

Comment: What do your $_SERVER super global variables contain? Do they show a get or a post request? Same inside the apache access log file? Get or post logged there?

Comment: You **are** sending a post request, but you are not sending a request body.

Comment: How do i send POST data if not through the url parameters? :)

Comment: Depends on your client, but for curl: http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Answer (score 0):

In your `<form>` tag, make sure the `method="POST"` attribute is present.

Comment: I'm using AJAX to call it not html forms

Comment: @rob. you need to make `POST` request. does not matter how.

Comment: Having the same issue, I ended up changing my whole API to GET requests because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was having the same problem and I discovered that the error was that I was using the wrong headers and the variables should be passed in the body of the request and not as URL parameters. I was using Postman to generate POST requests and I was getting $_GET filled and $_POST as (array(0)), so I read about $_POST superglobal and and it only gets filled when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request, according to PHP documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php. Then, I read the Postman manual and it shows at the print screens that the parameters must be at the body as explained here at the session request body: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests. As said by steve on his comment on your question, using curl this request should be formatted like this:

```
curl -X POST --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://example.com/resource.cgi
```